# vsfStream with cakephp 2.0 and PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, cakephp-2.4

I'm currently building some tests for my Image model which handles files and wanted to use vsfStream to test the file manipulations.

I can't seem to get my tests to recognise the vsfClass.

The vsfStream library is in app/Vendor/vsfStream

My ImageTest.php file is as follows:

```
 <?php
 App::uses('Image', 'Model');
 App::uses('vfsStream', 'Vendor');
 //App::import('Vendor', 'vfsStream', array('file' => 'vfsStream' . DS . 'vfsStream.php'));
 /**
  * Image Test Case
  *
  */
  class ImageTest extends CakeTestCase {

  /**
   * Fixtures
   *
   * @var array
   */
      public $fixtures = array(
    'app.image',
    'app.contractor',
    'app.project',
    'app.project_contractor',
    'app.project_image'
  );

 /**
  * setUp method
  *
  * @return void
  */
      public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
    $this->Image = ClassRegistry::init('Image');
            $this->root = vfsStream::setup('exampleDir');
  }

 ...more code
```

I get the error

Error: Class 'vfsStream' not found
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sgaluminium\app\Test\Case\Model\ImageTest.php
Line: 32

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that vsfStream was not loaded correctly. Did you load it with composer? I recommend you use this composer plugin: https://github.com/uzyn/cakephp-composer (read the how-to-use section on their website) and you write your composer.json like this:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit\/phpunit": "3.7.35",
        "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.2"
    }
}
```

This setup works very well in my project. In my test-file I use:

```
App::uses('vfsStream', 'Vendor');
```

just like you do.